# Creating a byte array from a string of hex in C

Tags: c

I've searched Stackoverflow, and there are many answers - but not to the exact problem that I'm seeing (using gcc on macOS, if that makes a difference - Mac specific suggestions won't do though because I need this to be cross platform).  I know how to convert a string to Hex into a buffer - or, at least, I thought I did.  I do it like this:

```
unsigned char* buffer_from_hexstring(char* string) {
    unsigned char* HexBuffer = (unsigned char *)malloc( (strlen(string) / 2) * sizeof(unsigned char) );

    for (size_t count = 0; count < strlen(string); count++) {
        sscanf(string, "%2hhx", &HexBuffer[count]);
        string += 2;
    }

    return HexBuffer;
}
```

I call my function as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* hexstring = "beefcafebeefcafebeefcafe";

    unsigned char* buffer = buffer_from_hexstring(hexstring);

    printf("Result: ");
    for(size_t count = 0; count < (sizeof(buffer) * sizeof(*buffer)); count++) {
        printf("%02x", buffer[count]);
    }

    free(buffer);
}
```

And the result that I get is `beefcafebeefcafe`. I'm missing a beefcafe.  In fact, whatever I do I only get 16bytes back - which is no useful if I want to convert more bytes.

I'm sure that it's an obvious error - but I can't see it.  Can you?

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` doesn't give you the size of your buffer.

Comment: ...it gives you the size of `buffer`, meaning the size of a pointer. You'll need to return both the buffer and its size.

Comment: You seem to have some misunderstanding about digits and bytes... You print 16 hexadecimal *digits* which is 8 *bytes*.

Comment: @some programmer dude - Damn.  Quite right.  I do understand the difference, but I can't see wood for the trees at the moment!

Comment: @tkausl, @ikegami - it's not perfect, but (in this case) it's correct.  A char is one byte so, whilst I agree that `count < sizeof(buffer)` isn't perfect it is the same as `count < (sizeof(buffer) * sizeof(*buffer))` in this instance. But, since you insist, I'll amend the code.  Doesn't fix the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the loop

```
for (size_t count = 0; count < strlen(string); count++)
```

iterates over *all* characters in the string `string`, but inside the loop you "extract" two characters at a time.

One simple solution is to iterate over *half* the length, since each hexadecimal number you extract is two digits:

```
for (size_t count = 0; count < strlen(string) / 2; count++)
```

You also make the same mistake when allocating memory for the `HexBuffer`, you allocate twice as much as needed.

You also need to take this into account when you print the values using the returned pointer.

Comment: These are definitely bugs that need fixing, but this doesn't answer the question. See the comments on the question.

Comment: Its a good point - but it doesn't solve the problem. In fact, I think a while loop is a better solution `while (strlen(string) > 0)` - but that doesn't solve the problem either.